# ParseUI error when working to add Facebook using swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform, parseui

So I am following the steps on the parse website ( https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers/iOS ) to add Facebook login. However Xcode is giving me the error '() -> FBSDKApplicationDelegate!' does not have a member named "application' for the following line of code in my app delegate file

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance.application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you are missing the parentheses for sharedInstance.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```